# Is there a connection between Heidegger's "anxiety" and Horkheimer's "subjective reason"?

Tags: metaphysics, heidegger, horkheimer

After reading "What is Metaphysics?" by Heidegger and "Eclipse of Reason" by Horkheimer, I'm left wondering if there is any apparent connection between how Heidegger described anxiety and Horkheimer's discussion about the rise of subjective reasoning in Means and Ends... If so, how so? If not, why not?

Comment: i would like to upvote the question, but don't understand it. why do you think there are overlaps?